# ""Missing argument in parameter list."" when trying to define a list of Site IDs

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have the following as part of a Power-Shell script:=

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$SiteIDs = (64898c8f-2d5f-4e0e-9a9b-eb9828975a9e,20e6140c-0441-4988-b36c-c61cf3400847)
```

where i am trying to define a list of site IDs, but the above is returning this error:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $SiteIDs = (64898c8f-2d5f-4e0e-9a9b-eb9828975a9e,20e6140c-0441-4988-b36c-c61cf3400847)
At line:1 char:49
+ $SiteIDs = (64898c8f-2d5f-4e0e-9a9b-eb9828975a9e,20e6140c-0441-4988-b ...
+                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SiteIDs` should probably be a *list of strings*. Therefore, you must put them into **quotes** (and you can omit the parentheses):

```
$SiteIDs = '64898c8f-2d5f-4e0e-9a9b-eb9828975a9e','20e6140c-0441-4988-b36c-c61cf3400847'
```

Comment: but as mentioned in this link @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-unifiedauditlog?view=exchange-ps#-siteids  they should be `values separated by commas: Value1, Value2,...ValueN.`

Comment: @johnGu I think they just omit the fact that you have to put the string into quotes. If you want to provide a single string, separated with commas, you could also do it like this: 'Guid1, Guid2, ...'  but I believe you must pass an array like in my answer.

Comment: it is surprising that Microsoft provide such a poor documentation, on other variables they explicitly mentioned to include the values in '' !!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case I have no idea what's wrong. The script has been working fine for years under PS ver 5.
7.3.1 though, throws this error in a line as simple as  this:

```
$OU365path = 'ou=Users,ou=O365,dc=contoso,dc=com'
```

and specifically underlines the first comma.
What's wrong here?
The same line, executed directly in the console does not throw an error.